# Where is fstab on my ubuntu?

Tags: fstab

were is my fstab and wats its name I looked in /etc. I have ubuntu 20.o4LTS I have tried looking on google it to I cant locate it

Comment: please read [ask] then [edit] your question with further details about what you tried to locate fstab

Answer (score 3):

The [fstab](/questions/tagged/fstab) tag info provide an answer to your question:

> `fstab` is an abbreviation of file system table. This file, located in `/etc`, contains information about static (non variable) file systems.

To display its content : `less /etc/fstab`

The path to file is mentioned in the `manpages` and the `info` page :

```
man fstab
info fstab
```

Comment: ... and more details are in `man fstab` or [online](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man5/fstab.5.html).

Comment: @N0rbert Thanks for this comment, I will add it to answer.